# How are calculated input S-box?

Tags: s-boxes

[image]
a) if input 1011

= 0 1 1 1

b) if input 0110

=
1 1 0 0

my answer right?

Comment: For b, if the input is 0110, the answer should be 0011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your answers are incorrect by my reading of the description. The leftmost bit can't change, since only the other three bits are rotated. That does make for a pretty terrible s-box, but it's an exercise anyway...

Comment: aha im understand you
1011  ===> 1110

0111 ===> 0111 same

Comment: 1011: Rotate the rightmost three bits right by one bit. 011 >>> 101. Therefore 1101.

0110: Rotate the rightmost three bits left by one bit: 110 <<< 101. Therefore 0101.